# What is the proof of the compatibility of a braiding with the unitors?

Tags: ct.category-theory, braided-tensor-categories

I am specifically referencing the property that, given a braided monoidal category with a braiding $c$ and left and right unitors $\lambda, \rho$,
$$
\lambda_A \circ c_{A,I}=\rho_{A},
$$
for any object $A$. This equation is stated in almost every reference (first done so by [Joyal and Street](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870883710558)) defining a braided category, yet an explicit or reproducible proof is, to my knowledge, not given anywhere. The closest thing to a proof I can find is a [series of hints on Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/920526/982236) asked in 2014, however this answer (by Turion) has several inconsistencies/typos, making it hard to understand. Is there some reference where this proof is actually 'spelled out'? How can one prove this relation given the braided monoidal category axioms?

Comment: My guess is that this can be reconstructed from the version for a symmetric monoidal category, which is identity (8) in Kelly's _On MacLane's conditions for coherence of natural associativities, commutativities, etc._ https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(64)90018-3 This is not an explicit proof, but at least it's published somewhere

Comment: A completely spelled out diagrammatic proof is given in [Proposition 1.3.21 of Volume II of Bimonoidal Categories, $E_n$-Monoidal Categories, and
Algebraic $K$-Theory](https://nilesjohnson.net/drafts/Johnson_Yau_ring_categories.pdf#page=502).

Comment: @Emily: Why not make that comment an answer? It seems a full and excellent answer, publicising a really useful book!

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Thanks! This is definitely a good idea; I hadn't thought about it as a chance to publicise Niles and Donald's really nice book(s)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the notation of [Joyal and Street](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870883710558) §2, here’s a proof of $\newcommand{\r}{\rho}\newcommand{\l}{\lambda}\newcommand{\x}{\otimes}\newcommand{\comp}{\!\!\cdot\!}\r_A = \l_A \comp c_{A,I}$.  Since $\l$ and $c$ are invertible, it suffices to prove $\r_A \comp (\l_A \comp c_{A,I} \x I) = \l_A \comp c_{A,I} \comp(\l_A \comp c_{A,I} \x I)$.  Notation: I will write composition as $\comp$, and it binds tighter than $\x$; and will write all associators just as $\alpha$, to reduce clutter.  I’ll black-box details of steps that are purely about symm. mon. cats., not involving the braiding — these are most easily seen using coherence for SMC’s.

$$\begin{align}
 \r_A \comp (\l_A \comp c_{A,I} \x I)
  &= (\l_A \comp c_{A,I}) \comp \r_{A \x I} & \text{naturality of $\r$} \\
  &= \l_A \comp c_{A,I} \comp (A \x \r_I) \comp \alpha & \text{SMC facts}\\
  &= \l_A \comp (\r_I \x A) \comp c_{A,I \x I} \comp \alpha & \text{naturality of $c$}\\
  &= \l_A \comp (\r_I \x A) \comp \alpha \comp (I \x c_{A,I}) \comp \alpha \comp (c_{A,I} \x I) & \text{axiom (B1)} \\
  &= \l_A \comp (I \x \l_A) \comp (I \x c_{A,I}) \comp \alpha \comp (c_{A,I} \x I) & \text{SMC facts}\\
  &= \l_A \comp (I \x \l_A \comp c_{A,I}) \comp \alpha \comp (c_{A,I} \x I)  & \text{functoriality of $\x$}\\
  &= (\l_A \comp c_{A,I}) \comp \l_{A \x I} \comp \alpha \comp (c_{A,I} \x I) & \text{naturality of $\l$}\\
  &= (\lambda_A \comp c_{A,I}) \comp (\lambda_A \x I) \comp (c_{A,I} \x I) & \text{SMC facts}\\
  &= (\lambda_A \comp c_{A,I}) \comp (\lambda_A \comp c_{A,I} \x I) & \text{functoriality of $\x$}
\end{align}
$$

I found this proof using string diagrams, writing down (B1) for $A,I,I$ (as Joyal and Street suggest), and then contemplating how to connect that to the desired equation.

Answer (score 5):

A completely spelled out diagrammatic proof is given in [Proposition 1.3.21 of Volume II of *Bimonoidal Categories, $E_n$-Monoidal Categories, and Algebraic K-Theory* by Niles Johnson and Donald Yau.](https://nilesjohnson.net/drafts/Johnson_Yau_ring_categories.pdf#page=502)

Comment: Incidentally, their other books are also very nice and extremely useful references; see [Colored Operads](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-170/), [Homotopical Quantum Field Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.08101), [Involutive Category Theory](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783030612023), [2-Dimensional Categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06055) (with Niles Johnson), and [Infinity Operads and Monoidal Categories with Group Equivariance](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.03839).

Comment: After reading more of it, this text is a great resource aside from just this proof, thanks!

Comment: @naahiv It's my pleasure! I \*really\* like these three (and their other) books too :)